# efficient way to display data in flutter app from a python script

Tags: python, flutter

For the sake of learning I scraped some Websites using Python and saved a list of objects.
Now I would like to display this list in a Flutter App.
The question is what would be the way to go?
I am familiar with fetching json data but would I need to upload my python data in order to fetch it in flutter?
Couldn't I do it somehow internally in the app?
Would I be able to run the script on mobile, just like I run it on my computer? I am working with a headless browser in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating an api via API Gateway from AWS.
Now I can call http requests to the created API via flutter app.
I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHcslTrkMz4) tutorial.